# Can the WPF RichTextBox content be serialized without FontFamily and FontSize?

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, rtf, flowdocument

Much like the editor you see on StackOverflow, I want users to be able to specify that parts of their text should be bold, italic, or underline, but I do not want them to be able to set the font size or family; these need to be inherited from somewhere else in the visual tree.

When placing the WPF RichTextBox control into an empty window and providing a few characters of text, the serialized representation of the rich text always includes the FontFamily. e.g., in LINQPad:

```
void Main()
{
    var window = new Window();
    var editor = new RichTextBox();
    window.Content = editor;
    window.ShowDialog();

    var rtf = RtfUtility.ConvertToRtf(editor.Document);
    rtf.Dump();
}
```

I entered "HELLO, WORLD!" into the RichTextBox.

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\htmautsp\deff2{\fonttbl{\f0\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f2\fcharset0 Segoe UI;}}{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;}\loch\hich\dbch\pard\plain\ltrpar\itap0{\lang1033\fs18\f2\cf0 \cf0\ql{\f2 {\ltrch HELLO, WORLD!}\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}}}
```

The RTF serialization code is nothing special:

```
var range = new TextRange(document.ContentStart, document.ContentEnd);
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    range.Save(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
    stream.Position = 0;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

The serialized representation references both *Times New Roman* and *Segoe UI*, but this is undesirable.

Is it possible to present rich text and inherit the font family and size from elsewhere, as well as serialize it without these properties?

I suppose an alternative is to set FontFamily and FontSize to whatever I want each time the text is deserialized -- but that just seems hacky. I'd also be open to an entirely different solution that does not involve RichTextBox, if that's feasible.

Answer (score 0):

FlowDocument assumes Sergoe UI as default font. This font is in the style for FlowDocument objects.

To change this:

```
editor.Document.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Times New Roman");
editor.Document.FontSize = 12;
```

You can also create a style for all FlowDocuments using xaml declarations in App.xaml or programmatically, for each FlowDocument:

```
var style = new Style(typeof(FlowDocument));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(FlowDocument.FontFamilyProperty, new FontFamily("Times New Roman")));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(FlowDocument.FontSizeProperty, 12));
editor.Resources.Add(typeof(FlowDocument), style)
```

When creating style for a paragraph (new Style(typeof(Paragraph))) you can also change each individual paragraph's settings.

Unfortunately serialization saves FlowDocument's resources and all settings which are not inherited.

Comment: I can definitely set the FontFamily/FontSize to whatever I want when the RichTextBox starts out empty, but if I'm editing text that I've deserialized, this won't work. Unless there's a better solution, it seems I will have to dig through all of the document elements and clear out all of the FontFamily/FontSize specifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a textrange:

```
TextRange tr2 = new TextRange(mergedDocument.ContentStart, mergedDocument.ContentEnd);
        tr2.ApplyPropertyValue(Span.FontFamilyProperty, font);
        tr2.ApplyPropertyValue(Span.FontSizeProperty, "24");
        tr2.ApplyPropertyValue(List.FontFamilyProperty, font);
        tr2.ApplyPropertyValue(List.FontSizeProperty, "24");
```